# Unity/Android Stencil Buffer not working

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

**Problem**

I'm developing an AR Project in Unity and I've tried this on different Devices, the weird thing is that it works only on some devices. Instead of going Transparent it displays weird Black Pixels(2nd Photo).
 Does anybody have an Idea?

Should I Clear the Buffer?
Has this something with the Stencil to do?
Or am I totally wrong on this?

**Working Devices**

Samsung Note 10.1 2014, 
Editor,
Huawei

**Not Working**

Samsung S2

[image]

[image]

[image]